# How to run Java code on Android device without uploading apk

Tags: java, android, compilation, apk

Is there an easy way to run Java code on an Android device without actually delivering an apk? I'd like to test out function calls without building an entire project.

For instance, it would be cool to run calls like `Camera.open(1)` and see what the device responds with. It takes forever to rebuild an entire project and redeploy it for minor changes. The only option I can come up with is having some sort of text field that takes user input, executes commands (Compiler API?) and displays the result. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

There is the Android Scripting Layer

https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

There is [Dev Apps Direct](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect) for looking and loading sample open source libraries.

There is [API Demos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hmh.api) which is just the official samples from the android sdk that a third party published on Google Play

Comment: that looks cool, thanks for sharing! How about running native Java code though?

Comment: If you think about it, we can't really use Java for that purpose, because declaring the type and initializing each Java variable/class/object would add extra lines of code each time we'd want to try out something on a command line. That is why Beanshell was created. Beanshell is just Java re-engineered as a scripting language so as to minimize the amount of boiler plate code you have to write in order to try out something. And on the Android Scripting Layer, Beanshell was also engineered to minimize the amount of boiler plate code for creating and running Android Activites, Services, etc.